# Conversion into MINLP

Tags: optimization, python, non-convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I want to solve the following optimization problem.

\begin{aligned}
  \text{Objective:} \hspace{1cm} & \text{maximize} \hspace{0.2cm} \sum_{s=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{N}}\left[\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^t (R_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})-C_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s}))\right]\\
  \text{where} \hspace{1cm}& R_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})=a_{1}\min(D_{t,s},x_{s})+a_{2}\min(D_{t,s},x_{s})*(a_{3}-a_{4}\epsilon_{t,s})  \\\text{     } \hspace{1cm}& C_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})=a_{5}+a_{6}x_{s}+a_{7}\min(D_{t,s},x_{s})+a_{8}\min(D_{t,s},x_{s})
\\
  \text{Constraints:} \hspace{1cm} & 0\leq x_{s}\leq x_{max}
\end{aligned}
$N,T, r,a_{1},\dots,a_{8}$, $x_{max}$ are all fixed constants.$\\$

**Variables**: $x_{s}$ (Total $N$ variables)

**Parameters**: $D_{t,s}$, $\epsilon_{t,s}$

I want to solve this problem using python (solver is not determined yet).

But as far as I know, it is difficult to embody objective function which contains minimization in python. So I introduced binary variables($z_{t,s}^1$, $z_{t,s}^2$) to remove min function such that the original problem was converted into **MINLP**.

\begin{aligned}
  \text{Objective:} \hspace{1cm} & \text{maximize} \hspace{0.2cm} \sum_{s=1}^{N}{\frac{1}{N}}\left[\sum_{t=1}^{T}\left(\frac{1}{1+r}\right)^t (R_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})-C_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s}))\right]\\
  \text{where} \hspace{1cm}& R_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})=z_{t,s}^1[a_{1}D_{t,s}+a_{2}D_{t,s}(a_{3}-a_{4}\epsilon_{t,s})]+z_{t,s}^2[a_{1}x_{s}+a_{2}x_{s}(a_{3}-a_{4}\epsilon_{t,s})]  
\\\text{     } \hspace{1cm}& C_{t,s}(x_{s},\epsilon_{t,s})=a_{5}+a_{6}x_{s}+z_{t,s}^1(a_{7}+a_{8}D_{t,s})+z_{t,s}^2(a_{7}+a_{8}x_{s})
\\
  \text{Constraints:} \hspace{1cm} & 0\leq x_{s}\leq x_{max}\\
                      \hspace{1cm} & z_{t,s}^1 + z_{t,s}^2=1 \quad (z_{t,s}^1, z_{t,s}^2 \textrm{ are binary})\\
                      \hspace{1cm} & x_{s} - D_{t,s}\leq 1000000z_{t,s}^1\\
                      \hspace{1cm} & D_{t,s} - x_{s}\leq 1000000z_{t,s}^2\\
\end{aligned}
$N,T,r,a_{1},\dots, a_{8}, x_{max}$ are all fixed constants.$\\$

**Variables**: $x_{s}$, $z_{t,s}^1$, $z_{t,s}^2$ (Total $N(1+2T)$ variables)

**Parameters**: $D_{t,s}$, $\epsilon_{t,s}$

I'm wondering if this conversion makes me solve the problem in python easier or not.

Can I solve this problem in python? If can, which solver do I have to use?

Comment: First, you cannot use the same binary variables $z^i_{t,s}$ in both the $R$ and $C$ constraints. Second, whether you need all those binary variables depends on the other parameters. Are $a_1, a_2, a_7, a_8$ all nonnegative? Is $a_3-a_4 \epsilon_{t,s}$ nonnegative?

Comment: @prubin sorry for looking at the comment late. (1) Can I ask why the same binary variables cannot be applied to both R and C? I think both R and C include same min(D_t,s, x_s), so same z1_t,s and z2_t,s can be applied. (2) a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 are all positive and a3−a4ϵt,s can be positive or negative (it depends on ϵt,s and ϵt,s is an uncertainty)

Comment: Sorry, I misread it and thought the arguments to min() were different between $R$ and $C$. I gather the $c_j$ in the second formulation are the same as the $a_j$ in the first formulation?

Comment: @prubin Oh, sorry for the confusion. a and c are same to each other. I'll edit it.